# Unable to get api server data from React

Tags: reactjs, api, laravel-5, axios

**Premise · What you want to realize**

I want to get json from API server using React's axios.

- Front end: React.js
- Back end: Laravel5.5

The authentication method uses Laravel default AUTH.

Since we want to return JSON only when logging in on the API side, we use middleware (auth) with Laravel routing.

**Problems occurring · Error messages**

If you hit api from the browser, it will be displayed normally, but if you go through React's axios you get the following error. 401 (Unauthorized)

[It can be taken by accessing from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXoof.png)

**Source Codes**

■React.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const host = window.location.protocol + '//api.' + window.location.hostname ;
const path = window.location.pathname

export const getIndex = nowId =>
  axios
    .get(host + '/v1/movie/' + nowId, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
       },
     })
    .then((results) => {
      const status = results.status
      if(typeof result === 'undefind'){
        return  status
      }
      const indexDatas = results.data[0]
      return  indexDatas
    }).catch(
    error => {}
);
```

■Laravel (API)

・/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/auth/login/{token}', 'Auth\LoginController@auth');
Route::get('/auth/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('/v1/sidemenu', 'ChallengersController@sidemenu');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'v1', 'middleware' => ['auth']],function(){
    // Movie
    // =======
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'movie', 'middleware' => ['cors']],function(){
        Route::get('/contents', 'MovieController@contents');
        Route::get('/addContents', 'MovieController@addContents');
        Route::get('/{id}/getChapter', 'MovieController@getChapter');
        Route::get('/{id}/getReview', 'MovieController@getReview');
        Route::get('/{id}/reviewCount', 'MovieController@getReviewCount');
        Route::post('/postReview', 'MovieController@postReview');
        Route::get('/review/commit', 'MovieController@reviewCommit');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'MovieController@detail');
        Route::get('/list', 'MovieController@index');
    });

    // Podcast
    // =======
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'audio'],function(){
        Route::get('/list', 'PodcastController@index');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'PodcastController@detail');
    });

    // Lecture
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'lecture'],function(){
        Route::get('/', 'LecturesController@index');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'LecturesController@show');
        Route::get('/{id}/schedules', 'LectureSchedulesController@index'); 
    });
});
```

・/config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Is the solution to this problem to give authentication information to the header of the request side (React's axios)?

Then, what kind of things should be put in the header?
I tried putting the same thing as the figure below, but it did not move.

[API Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g9lY.png)

```
    axios
    .get(host + '/v1/movie/' + nowId, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Set-Cookie': 'laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IitBVldGM0VORzFZRk1ick1IY2Z5d1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT3JPeUVHc3BSaE5vRXF0KzB3N2xXRkdXb0xwMDVvS0RZR1VQM0xmMFkySnNrS01KRHVXMTFWNVhTU1wvMTVwa3RDRmNvajVMZGhiU2t4dFEzY1FxdkFnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJjMjJhYWQ3ZjczMDgwOTExZDI5Njc5OTY4YTg5ZjgxMGI1MDlmYmNkZDJkZTFmNDA5YWMyZjRjOTYxYzc0YzNlIn0%3D;'
       },
     })
    .then((results) => {
      const status = results.status
      if(typeof result === 'undefind'){
        return  status
      }
      const indexDatas = results.data[0]
      return  indexDatas
    }).catch(
    error => {}
);
```

Comment: It seem to use cookie to authenticate.You should set option `withCredentials: true` in `axios` config to save cookie after login

Answer (score 0):

your are able to open in browser, because you have added the routes in web.php.
in order to open from api , you have to add routes in api.php.